# Wordpress plugin/code for creating new website in a multisite for user/member with payments option.

Tags: wordpress, subscription, membership, multisite

I am looking for a wordpress plugin/code for a multisite where the new user can register with payment and creates a new website in our multisite. The admin dashboard can view all the users/members details, payment details, expiration date of his/her website etc. Also the new user/member can see his/her details on dashboard about current subscription plan, expiration date, and link to renew subscription etc. Hope you find a suitable code/plugin that can help me.

Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The premium plugin [WP Ultimo](https://codecanyon.net/item/wp-ultimo-easily-create-a-premium-network-of-sites/19527147) has subscription plans and payments for making sites in a WordPress multisite. There is a demo available [here](https://demo.wpultimo.com/wp-login.php). It is 5 star rated and recently updated.

Comment: Thanks for your help. One question I want to ask is what happens when the user subscription ends? Is the site deleted or redirected to do renew subscription.

Comment: @user2022526 I don't know, but you can ask the plugin author with a comment here https://codecanyon.net/item/wp-ultimo-easily-create-a-premium-network-of-sites/19527147/comments (requires to register for a free account first in the site)